# Dropwizard/JDBI - Per-field mapping of MySQL INT to Java boolean?

Tags: java, dropwizard, mapper, jdbi

My database contains many columns where booleans are represented by a 0 or a 1. I'd like to convert these to booleans when they are mapped from the database while retaining the ability to use `@RegisterBeanMapper(Dog.class)` for most of the other fields.

I'm wondering if there's some way to use the standard bean mapper, but apply a custom mapper on a *per field* basis, like this:

```
class Dog {
    String name;
    int legCount;
    @Mapper(BooltegerMapper.class)
    boolean isSnifferous;
}
```

Most columns would be automagically mapped, while `isSnifferous` would use the BooltegerMapper that converts an Integer to boolean.

Comment: When you use: `@RegisterBeanMapper(Dog.class)`

Comment: Jdbi project member here. If _all_ booleans in your database are stored as numbers, then you can simply register a mapper that converts the number to boolean. Any built-in mapper can be overridden simply by registering a new mapper for the already-supported type. Last-registered mapper wins for any given type.

Comment: If you have a max of true booleans and numeric booleans, your mapper could use `ResultSet.getMetaData().getColumnType(columnNumber)` to differentiate between them and fetch the value according to the column type.